# Why does there need to be backslash before dot?

Tags: python, python-re

Hello I have pattern for email adress and it works but I am struggling, why there need to be backslash before dot

```
 pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
```

Comment: Look for "special characters" in the docs - [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: try https://www.regexr.com